# Run a batch file at boot

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm booting up a machine using a CD that runs a batch file, that applies an image to a machine using diskpart and imagex that formats the C drive and applies a custom .wim file. It basically formats the C drive and installs WES (Windows XP) operating system.

The user boots up from the CD, types in D:\Install.bat and off it runs.

This might seem a bit pointless, but I want to alter the boot behaviour to run the Install.bat file at boot time. So the user simply chucks in a disk and off it goes installing everything, instead of the user manually changing directories and calling the batch file.

I've tried using the Task Schedular and creating a registry file, but the Task Schedular didn't work and the registry file only worked when the user logged in.

Is there a way to change the boot up behaviour so it simply runs the Install.bat batch file?

I know this might not be the right place for the question but I didnt really know where to put it!

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I've also tried placing the batch file inside the Startup folder, but this just runs it when I log in. What I want is for my Install.bat file to run before Windows even loads up.

Comment: Have you tried placing your batch-file in the startup folder?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that in my question, yes I have, but this calls up as I log into Windows, I want my Install.bat file to run before Windows even runs.

Comment: run the scheduled task as user SYSTEM and with ONSTART. See `schtasks /create /?` - parameters `/SD` and `/RU` (or `/U` if you want it to run as a defined user)

Comment: I can't comprehend: what the hell has _[booting up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting) a machine from CD_ in common with currently installed Windows Task Scheduler or its Registry or its Startup folder?